# Is http.ServerResponse.write() blocking?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, blocking, httpserver

Is it possible to write non-blocking response.write? I've written a simple test to see if other clients can connect while one downloads a file:

```
var connect = require('connect');

var longString = 'a';
for (var i = 0; i < 29; i++) { // 512 MiB
   longString += longString;
}
console.log(longString.length)

function download(request, response) {
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", longString.length);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="file"');
    response.write(longString);
    response.end();
}

var app = connect().use(download);
connect.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

And it seems like `write` is blocking!

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update** So, it doesn't block and it blocks in the same time. It doesn't block in the sense that two files can be downloaded simultaneously. And it blocks in the sense that creating a buffer is a long operation.

Answer (score 2):

Any processing done strictly in JavaScript will block. [`response.write()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.19/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding), at least as of v0.8, is [no exception](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.8.19/lib/http.js#L703-L739) to this:

> The first time `response.write()` is called, it will send the buffered header information and the first body to the client. The second time `response.write()` is called, Node assumes you're going to be streaming data, and sends that separately. That is, the response is buffered up to the first chunk of body.
>
> Returns `true` if the entire data was flushed successfully to the kernel buffer. Returns `false` if all or part of the data was queued in user memory. `'drain'` will be emitted when the buffer is again free.

What may save some time is to convert `longString` to `Buffer` before attempting to `write()` it, since the conversion will occur anyways:

```
var longString = 'a';
for (...) { ... }
longString = new Buffer(longString);
```

But, it would probably be better to [stream](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.19/api/stream.html#stream_writable_stream) the various chunks of `longString` rather than all-at-once (Note: [Streams are changing in v0.10](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Api-changes-between-v0.8-and-v0.10)):

```
var longString = 'a',
    chunkCount = Math.pow(2, 29),
    bufferSize = Buffer.byteLength(longString),
    longBuffer = new Buffer(longString);

function download(request, response) {
    var current = 0;

    response.setHeader("Content-Length", bufferSize * chunkCount);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="file"');

    function writeChunk() {
        if (current < chunkCount) {
            current++;

            if (response.write(longBuffer)) {
                process.nextTick(writeChunk);
            } else {
                response.once('drain', writeChunk);
            }
        } else {
            response.end();
        }
    }

    writeChunk();
}
```

And, if the eventual goal is to stream a file from disk, this can be even easier with [`fs.createReadStream()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.19/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) and [`stream.pipe()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.19/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipe_destination_options):

```
function download(request, response) {
    // response.setHeader(...)
    // ...

    fs.createReadStream('./file-on-disk').pipe(response);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `process.nextTick` is for? Is it the same as  setTimeout?

Comment: @Vanuan Corrected for `2^29`. And, I used [`process.nextTick()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.19/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) so each chunk is written in a different tick of the event loop.

Comment: And what is `response.one`?

Comment: @Vanuan Should be `once` rather than `one`. But it's [`EventEmitter.once()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.19/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener) as `http.ServerResponse` inherits from `EventEmitter`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it does not block, I tried one from IE and other from firefox. I did IE first but still could download file from firefox first.
I tried for 1 MB (i < 20) it works the same just faster.
You should know that whatever longString you create requires memory allocation. Try to do it for i < 30 (on windows 7) and it will throw FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory.

It takes time for memory allocation/copying nothing else. Since it is a huge file, the response is time taking and your download looks like blocking. Try it yourself for smaller values (i < 20 or something)

Comment: Isn't that string created only once, on server startup?

Comment: Yes it is, but response is constructed for every request. So it gets copied for each response. Response is I/O intensive and also consider its huge size.

Comment: For me, 1 MB is loaded in less than a second, how did you manage to click so fast?

Comment: I tried for i<30,28(256MB),26(128MB) and so on. For 1MB, I just open the link in two different browsers, but didnt save, if it is blocking the one opened afterwards cant start and finish before the second.

Comment: Are you aware of that even if don't click save, browser still downloads a file to a temporary location?

Comment: Oh, it seems like it is only Chrome's behavior

Comment: What I was checking was if it was blocking or not. If browser was able to download both files simultaneously, then it cant be blocking, it can serve both requests. 1 MB was just a test case.

Comment: Thanks! I understand better now.